# How do I change the 'results' fieldname in Django REST Framework to something else?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST framework, and PageNumberPagination class for serializing the model contents. It outputs as follows:

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar"
    }
}
```

How do I change the `results` fieldname in the output to something else? Like `foo_results` or `authors` or whatever I want?

I am using generic viewsets and serializers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by docs [custom-pagination-styles](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) you can try

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):

        return Response({
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'WHATDOYOUWANTHERE': data,
            # ^^^^^^^^^^
        })
```

and if you want set it as default in the settings update data for paginator

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.core.pagination.CustomPagination',
     #                      ^^^ CHANGE PATH TO YOUR PAGINATOR CLASS ^^^
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

or include to your viewset by parameter [modifying-the-pagination-style](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style)

```
pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

Comment: This was the way for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the official [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#example).

Create a custom pagination class like in the example:

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results''foo_results': data
        })
```

In your `settings.py` put the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'path.to.your.custom.pagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```